# Parsing '.cer' format for website

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to parse data from the '.cer' format into plain text that I can use on the site. For this purpose, [this library](https://lapo.it/asn1js/) is suitable but I can not understand how to use it, maybe someone used it, and can give advice?

[File example file, you can load this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Byo89V5VmyDrYjdLUDRhS2lGdkE).

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named "What topics can I ask about here?" and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?". And more importantly, please read the Stack Overflow question checklist: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist. You might also want to learn about Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples.

Comment: Please include the relevant information in the question. Obscure links may well lead to all kinds of stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var encoded_string = /* your string */;
var input = ASN1.decode(Base64.unarmor(encoded_string));
```

Access properties such as `typeName` and `sub`:

```
function buildJSON(input, output){
    Object.assign(output, {
        type: input.typeName(),
        content: input.content()
    });
    output.sub = [];
    if(input.sub){
        for(var sub of input.sub){
            var obj = {};
            buildJSON(sub, obj)
            output.sub.push(obj);
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Remember to load the required scripts and in order:

1. hex.js
2. base64.js
3. int10.js
4. asn1.js

You should combine the scripts before using it in production.

See it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/bgz86cvp/

Read the docs: https://github.com/lapo-luchini/asn1js/blob/master/dom.js#L51